# No tls.crt on certificate secret

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I am creating a ClusterIssuer and a Certificate. However, there is ***no*** `tls.crt` on the secret! What I am doing wrong?

The clusterissuer looks like is running fine, but neither the keys has the crt

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-myapp-clusterissuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: app@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: wildcard-myapp-com
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          cloudDNS:
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-service-account
              key: dns-service-account.json
            project: app
        selector:
          dnsNames:
            - '*.myapp.com'
            - myapp.com
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: myapp-com-tls
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: myapp-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-myapp-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: '*.myapp.com'
  dnsNames:
    - 'myapp.com'
    - '*.myapp.com'
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided it is very hard to troubleshoot this, you could be hitting this [bug](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/2111).

You can start troubleshooting this kind of issues by following this procedure:

1. Get the certificate request name:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe certificate myapp-com-tls
...
Created new CertificateRequest resource "myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx"
```

2. The request will generate an order, get the order name with the command:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe certificaterequests myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx
…
Created Order resource <namespace>/myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx-xxxxx
```

3. The order will generate a challenge resource, get that with:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe order myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx-xxxxx
…
Created Challenge resource "myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx" for domain "yourdomain.com"
```

4. Finally, with the challenge name, you can get the status of the validation for you certificate:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe challenges myapp-com-tls-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
...
  Reason:      Successfully authorized domain                                                                                                                                                                      
...
  Normal  Started         2m45s  cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented       2m45s  cert-manager  Presented challenge using http-01 challenge mechanism
  Normal  DomainVerified  2m22s  cert-manager  Domain "yourdomain.com" verified with "http-01" validation
```

If the status of the challenge is other than `DomainVerified`, then something went wrong while requesting the certificate from let's encrypt and will see a reason in the output.

Comment: I agree with you. The cause was because the certificate are in pending state

Comment: The pending state can be retrieved by running `kubectl describe -A Certificaterequests`.